# In the context of RESTful API what is the correct way to UPDATE/DELETE resource that you have to apply filter on

Tags: rest, api

If I have the following case:

```
class Car
   int id
   int owenerId
   string color
   string model
   Set<Key> keys

class Key
   int id
   carId
   ownerId
```

and the strange business case that a car is uniquely identified by owner, color and model
how is the correct way to go about my RESTful API

GET /cars/owners/{ownerId}?color=black&model=BMW

that would be my GET request, considering owner is a resource and color and model are properties of the car resource

I also have an idea what my POST might look like

```
POST /cars/owners/{ownerId}
{
    "color": "black",
    "model": "BMW",
    "keyIds" : [123,234,546]
}
```

How would I go about my PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests given that I want to manipulate the keys collection.
Is this PUT valid following the RESTful way

```
PUT /cars/owners/{ownerId}?color=black&model=BMW
{
    "keyIds": [344,3453]
}
```

What if I have to use POST to update my resource for whatever reason (for example some JAX-RS versions don't have PATCH annotation)

I cannot go /cars/owners/{ownerId}?color=black&model=BMW/update, so how would I go about my request

Did I get the whole REST thing completely wrong?

Comment: stack overflow is really good for questions that have specific answers, but less good for: write a good reference for general URL design. I'm going to delete my answer because based on your comments I don't think I will be able to answer it specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside that this is a bit weird, but you're saying that your *primary key* is a combination owner/color and model.

The primary way to *identify* this in your REST API is through a url with the following pattern:

```
/cars/owners/{ownerId}?color=black&model=BMW
```

Then, I would assume that the `PUT` request uses an identical url:

```
/cars/owners/{ownerId}?color=black&model=BMW
```

> How would I go about my PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests given that I want to manipulate the keys collection. Is this PUT valid following the RESTful way

The specific example you share doesn't seem right. `PUT` should replace the state of the target entirely, and if you only specify `keyIds`, and only update that property, a `PATCH` might be more appropriate.

> What if I have to use POST to update my resource for whatever reason (for example some JAX-RS versions don't have PATCH annotation)
>
> I cannot go /cars/owners/{ownerId}?color=black&model=BMW/update, so how would I go about my request

I don't fully understand what the problem is here. You can do a POST request however you want.

Anyway, all of this does look a bit messy, so a few recommendations for clearer URL design:

First of all, it seems like you do actually have an `id` in your Car class, so you could make it way easier on yourself by just using:

```
/car/{id}
```

This also means that your urls will be stable if the owner changes. Query parameters are more often used for filtering/searching and less often for identification of a specific resource, so here's another URL pattern that will be clearer:

```
/owner/{ownerId}/cars/BMW/black
```

It does beg the question, what if the owner has 2 black BMW's, so this has to be a unique key.

Generally these are the patters for interacting with this:

```
GET /owner/{ownerId}/cars/BMW/black <- retrieve current state
PUT /owner/{ownerId}/cars/BMW/black <- replace current car, or create a new car
DELETE /owner/{ownerId}/cars/BMW/black <- remove car
PATCH /owner/{ownerId}/cars/BMW/black <- partially update the car
```

And again, I don't fully understand why you need POST, but if you're using `POST` as a substitute for PATCH, there's no reason why you also can't use the same url pattern.

Comment: Kind of messed up example that I gave, sorry for that.
But yet again, you say query parameters are for filtering, considering that "color" and "model" are properties of the resource "Car" wouldn't it be right to use query parameters to specify them, having in mind that it is recommended that path parameters are used to access resources like for example is the owner
Also, is it really a bad practice to access the resource from /cars instead of from /owners because I feel like /owners implies that you will get information about the owner while we actually intend to get information about /cars

Comment: @GSHTR, well, it's pretty common to do something like `/articles/x/authors` to find a list of authors associated with an article, so similarly it's not that strange to get `/owner/x/cars` to get cars associated with an owner and `/owner/x/cars/y` to get a specific one.

Comment: If I see something like `/owner/x/cars?foo=1&bar=2`, I would expect to still get a _list_ of cards, but filtered by `foo=1` and `bar=2`, I would not expect this to be 1 unique url related to 1 specific car.

Comment: Does that mean that whenever I want to access a specific resource like the example with the car, I would go all the way using path parameters and if I want a list I would then use query parameters?What if car had another property lets say tyres model(stupid example again) /owner/{ownerId}/cars/BMW/black/michelin, this does look kinda out of place and not really to the point what you are actually accessing.Isn't it more appropraite to add /cars/model/BMW/color/black/tyres/michelin but yet again, it starts to look like a nonsense URI.I feel like I am super confused over something very simple

Comment: Maybe you could give a better example following the same idea or a reference API that is a little more complex than the standard API's shown on tutorials that are very basic